# onsubmit does not work when function loaded from module

Tags: javascript

I have following code structure:

```
index.html
./js/addUserFunction.js
./js/addUserModule.js
./js/app.js
./js/getUsers.js
./js/package.json
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Company</title>

    <!-- this works -->
    <script type="module" src="./js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- this works -->
    <script src="./js/addUserFunction.js"></script>

    <!-- this dos not works:
        Uncaught ReferenceError: addUser is not defined
    -->
    <!-- <script type="module" src="./js/addUserModule.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="frmAddUser" onsubmit="addUser(); return false">
      <input name="txtName" type="text" placeholder="name" />
      <input name="txtLastName" type="text" placeholder="last name" />
      <button>Add user</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**addUserFunction.js**

```
async function addUser() {
  console.log("addUser called");
}
```

**addUserModule.js**

```
async function addUser() {
  console.log("addUser called");
}

export { addUser };
```

**app.js**

```
import { getUsers } from "./getUsers.js";

getUsers();
```

**getUsers.js**

```
async function getUsers() {
  console.log("getUsers called");
}

export { getUsers };
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

If I try to use **addUser** from **addUserFunction.js** then everything is working. But if I try to use **addUser** from **addUserModule.js** then I got the error that addUser is not defined.

What is this happening?

**EDIT**
I've tried update to **addUserModule.js** to following:

```
async function addUser(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("addUser called");
}

export { addUser };
```

but I got same error

**EDIT**

Seems that following worked:

```
async function addUser() {
  console.log("addUser called");
}

window.addUser = addUser;
export { addUser };
```

Can somebody explain magic behind this?

Whole project is available here https://easyupload.io/grfegs

Comment: Modules have their own scope. All declarations inside a module are scoped to the module. When you try to access these declarations outside module it will throw a reference error. They don't create globals unless you do so explicitly. That's why `window.addUser = addUser` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access that function in the `onsubmit` in the main html file because you didn't `import` it

```
 <form id="frmAddUser" onsubmit="addUser(); return false">
```

I would recommend not using inline javascript at all when you use modules. Instead use event listeners in your .js file, something like this:

```
 import { addUser } from "./AddUserModule.js"

 document.querySelector("#frmAddUser").addEventListener("submit", () => addUser())
```